# Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Tags: python, mysql

what i would want to do in this program is to send a data  after manipulate it to a specefic table called conjugaison_présent in a database , but when i used the function cursor.executemany()<in the code is mycursor.executemany()> the second parameter is just like wouldn't passed, although the format of it is correct (list of tuples), but when i put another simple list of tuples instead of the actual data it's passed,
i have tried to see if its data type is not true by used type() method but it gave me list and here is the error:
`raise errors.ProgrammingError( mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type`  
_ This is the code:

```
def conjugate_1er_gr_pré():

    mycursor.execute("SELECT nom FROM conjugaison_verbe WHERE groupe = 1")
    vrbs1gr = mycursor.fetchall()
    termi_1_gr = ['e', 'es', 'e', 'ons', 'ez', 'ent']
    
    res = np.array([])
    
    result = []
    for x in vrbs1gr:
        # converting the data type of vrbs1gr from tuple to string
        y = str(x)
        # Slicing from the beginning
        y = y[2:]
        # Slicing from the end
        global z
        z = y[:-3]
        for j in termi_1_gr:
            m = z.replace("er", j)
            result.append(m)
            arr = np.append(res, result)
    

    def slicer(n, iterable):
        args = [iter(iterable)] * n
        return zip(*args)
    arr1 = slicer(6, arr)

    return tuple(arr1)

sql = "INSERT INTO conjugaison_présent (je,tu,il,nous,vous,ils) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);"
vals = conjugate_1er_gr_pré()
val = list(vals)
print(val)
mycursor.executemany(sql,val)
mydb.commit()
```

and the printed 'val' like:

```
[('joue', 'joues', 'joue', 'jouons', 'jouez', 'jouent'), ('passe', 'passes', 'passe', 'passons', 'passez', 'passent'), ('travaille', 'travailles', 'travaille', 'travaillons', 'travaillez', 'travaillent'), ('achete', 'achetes', 'achete', 'achetons', 'achetez', 'achetent')]
```

please any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Try to change your function to this.

```py
def conjugate_1er_gr_pré():

    mycursor.execute("SELECT nom FROM conjugaison_verbe WHERE groupe = 1")
    vrbs1gr = mycursor.fetchall()
    termi_1_gr = ['e', 'es', 'e', 'ons', 'ez', 'ent']

    res = []

    for verb in vrbs1gr:

        # The first element of the tuple is the verb, which is probably the only element based on your select
        verb = verb[0]

        # now we can create the replace with a tuple creation with list comprehension
        conj = tuple(verb.replace(er, termination) for termination in termi_1_gr)

        res.append(conj)

    return res
sql = "INSERT INTO conjugaison_présent (je, tu, il, nous, vous, ils) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"
vals = conjugate_1er_gr_pré()
print(vals)
mycursor.executemany(sql, vals)
mydb.commit()
```

This will return you a list of tuples with 6 elements, which is expected by executemany. Pay attention to your query, you're missing a space after VALUES.

Comment: raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`counjigaison`.`conjugaison_présent`, CONSTRAINT `conjugaison_présent_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `conjugaison_verbe` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

Comment: Ok, at least now the error changed. You are missing the conjugaison_verbe(id). You should add it to the select query, to the tuple and to the insert query. Could you share some more information on the columns of this tables and its relationships?

Comment: thank you sir for your great support , and i am so sorry for wasting your time , the mistake i have done is to insert manually the ids (verb_id)in the conjugaison_présent table which is a foreign key that is incremented automatically,This stupid bug  that i done cost me 5 days, and i really appreciate your support, tnx again

Answer (score 0):

You may try looping through the list of tuples:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO conjugaison_présent (je,tu,il,nous,vous,ils) 
VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);"
vals = conjugate_1er_gr_pré()
val = list(vals)
print(val)
for x in val:
    mycursor.executemany(sql,x)
    mydb.commit()
```

Comment: raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement

Comment: i also have changed mycursor.executemany(sql,x) to mycursor.execute(sql,x) cause it's not multiple rows in this case but i got this error:    raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'str_' cannot be converted to a MySQL type